# How to resolve css loader in webpack config?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, css-loader

I am trying to set up a react project and managed to add components correctly.  Now I am trying to add css to this project but I having a hard time.

I have tried numerous approaches with no result and I have some basic knowledge of how to go about it however no attempt worked.  I have added the loader and the necessary plugins but I always get an error.  One approach I have tried and which I believe to be the correct one is the following:

```
npm install --save-dev style-loader css-loader
```

Then in rules.js:

```
...
{
    test: /\.css$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']

}
```

These are my files:

paths.js

```
import path from 'path';

module.exports = {
    root: path.resolve(__dirname, '../', '../'),
    outputPath: path.resolve(__dirname, '../', '../', 'build'),
    entryPath: path.resolve(__dirname, '../', '../', 'src/index.js'),
    templatePath: path.resolve(__dirname, '../', '../', 'public/index.html'),
    imagesFolder: 'images',
    fontsFolder: 'fonts',
    cssFolder: 'css'
}
```

rules.js

```
module.exports = [
    {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
            loader: 'babel-loader'
        }
    },
    {
        test: /\.eot(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'file-loader'
    },
    {
        test: /\.(woff|woff2)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'url-loader?prefix=font/&limit=5000'
    },
    {
        test: /\.ttf(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=application/octet-stream'
    },
    {
        test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i,
        use: ['url-loader?limit=10000', 'img-loader']
    }
];
```

webpack.common.babel.js

```
import webpack from 'webpack';
import HtmlWebpackPlugin from 'html-webpack-plugin';

import paths from './paths';
import rules from './rules';

module.exports = {
    entry: paths.entryPath,
    module: {
        rules
    },
    resolve: {
        modules: ['src', 'node_modules'],
        extensions: ['*', '.js', '.scss', '.css']
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.ProgressPlugin(),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: paths.templatePath,
            minify: {
                collapseInlineTagWhitespace: true,
                collapseWhitespace: true,
                preserveLineBreaks: true,
                minifyURLs: true,
                removeComments: true,
                removeAttributeQuotes: true
            }
        })
    ]
};
```

webpack.dev.babel.js

```
import webpack from 'webpack';

import paths from './paths';
import rules from './rules';

module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
    output: {
        filename: '[name].js',
        path: paths.outputPath,
        chunkFilename: '[name].js'
    },
    module: {
        rules
    },
    performance: {
        hints: 'warning',
        maxAssetSize: 450000,
        maxEntrypointSize: 8500000,
        assetFilter: assetFilename => {
            return (
                assetFilename.endsWith('.css') || assetFilename.endsWith('.js')
            );
        }
    },
    optimization: {
        splitChunks: {
            chunks: 'all'
        }
    },
    devServer: {
        contentBase: paths.outputPath,
        compress: true,
        hot: true,
        historyApiFallback: true
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
    ]
};
```

webpack.prod.babel.js

```
import CleanWebpackPlugin from 'clean-webpack-plugin';

import paths from './paths';
import rules from './rules';

module.exports = {
    mode: 'production',
    output: {
        filename: `${paths.jsFolder}/[name].[hash].js`,
        path: paths.outputPath,
        chunkFilename: '[name].[chunkhash].js'
    },
    module: {
        rules
    },
    plugins: [
        new CleanWebpackPlugin([paths.outputPath.split('/').pop()], {
            root: paths.root
        })
    ],
    devtool: 'source-map'
};
```

webpack.config.js

```
require('@babel/register');
const webpackMerge = require('webpack-merge');

const common = require('./config/webpack/webpack.common.babel');

const envs = {
    development: 'dev',
    production: 'prod'
};

/* eslint-disable global-require,import/no-dynamic-require */
const env = envs[process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development'];
const envConfig = require(`./config/webpack/webpack.${env}.babel`);
module.exports = webpackMerge(common, envConfig);
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "photoly",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server --open"
  },
  "author": "Nikolas Pitsillos",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.4.4",
    "@babel/core": "^7.4.5",
    "@babel/node": "^7.4.5",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.4.4",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread": "^7.4.4",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^7.2.0",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-import-meta": "^7.2.0",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-async-to-generator": "^7.4.4",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.4.4",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.4.5",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/register": "^7.4.4",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.4.5",
    "babel-core": "^7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.1",
    "babel-jest": "^24.8.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^2.0.2",
    "eslint": "^5.16.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^17.1.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^4.3.0",
    "eslint-loader": "^2.1.2",
    "eslint-plugin-babel": "^5.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.17.2",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.13.0",
    "file-loader": "^3.0.1",
    "html-loader": "^0.5.5",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "img-loader": "^3.0.1",
    "prettier": "^1.17.1",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.0.0",
    "url-loader": "^1.1.2",
    "webpack": "^4.32.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.4.1",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.2.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "cross-env": "^5.2.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-beta.8",
    "react-redux": "^7.0.3",
    "redux": "^4.0.1",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0"
  }
}
```

This is my index.js file:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import App from './components/app/App';

import '../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap'

ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

The error I get after running npm start

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css 7:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (7:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|  * Licensed under MIT (https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/LICENSE)
|  */
> :root {
|   --blue: #007bff;
|   --indigo: #6610f2;
 @ ./src/index.js 4:0-54
```

Thank you for your help in advance.  If this is too complicated to solve can someone please point me to a working tutorial with a full setup for react, webpack, babel and support for css/sass styling?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about your files and code, But one thing that I can see is that you have tried to install `css-loader` and `style-loader`, however i can not find them in your `package.json` file.

Check whether they are installed correctly or not

And for installing css-loader. Do not install the latest version 3.0.0.

Instead try `npm i --save css-loader@2.1.1`

Also,

Replace the following code in your rules.js file

```
 {
     test: /\.css$/,
     exclude: /node_modules/,
     use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']

 }
```

with the following code

```
{
    test: /\.css$/,
    loader:
      "style-loader!css-loader?modules=true&localIdentName=[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]"
}
```